# QStackedWidget indexes update

Tags: qt

After removing a widget from a QStackedWidget I want to update the indexes of the widgets in accordance with their corresponding positions.
Probably i would need a loop for that; please how do i go about this.

Answer (score 1):

1) When a widget is removed, a signal - `widgetRemoved(int index)`  is emitted.

2) By using the function `count()` you can get the number of widgets.

So now, you know index of removed widget and the total number of widgets. Use these information to set the index of other widgets accordingly using the function `setCurrentIndex(int index)` .